# How add configurable product for selected options magento 2 programatically?

Tags: configurable-product, products, magento-2.1.7, programmatically

I want to add configurable product pragmatically.
If product is ABC it has 3 size options XS M L so I want to add all options same time only changeable thing is quantity. I tried but it added as first selected option 3 times, need help.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have tried ajax method,Its worked but should have write wait method.

```
// -------------- add this function to custom.js file. -----------

function fncSubmitAjax(){
   var customurl = 
   jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
   var flag =false;
   var arrOptions = new Array();
   var productId =  jQuery("input[name='productId'").val();
   jQuery(".sproduct_qty").each(function () {
         var qty = jQuery('#' + this.id).val();
         if(qty > 0){
             var name = jQuery('#' + this.id).attr('name');
             var optionId =  name; 
             var vid  = name.replace('qty','size_id');
             var optionValueId = jQuery("input[name='"+vid+"'").val();
              arrOptions.push({'option_id':optionId,"option_value_id":optionValueId,"qty":qty});
             flag = true;
         }
     });
     if(flag){
         for (var i = 0; i < arrOptions.length; i++) {
             jQuery.ajax({
                 url: customurl,
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: {
                     action:'addWholeSale',
                     id:productId,
                     options:arrOptions[i],
                 },
                 complete: function(response) {
                     if (response.responseJSON.success == 'true') {
                         // Update minicart after product add
                         require([
                           'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
                           ], function (customerData) {
                               var sections = ['cart'];
                               customerData.invalidate(sections);
                               customerData.reload(sections, true);

                           });
                           // end update minicart
                         // ---------------- Open Minicart --------------
                          jQuery('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentUpdated', function ()  {});
                         // --------------- End -------------------------
                         }
                       },
                       error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                         console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                     }
                 });
         }
         // return true;
       }
      else{
         alert('Please add quantity in one of the option');
         return false;
      }

    }
            ------------------------------------ Add this to  Product add Controller 
            ---------------------------- AddItems.php under execute() funtion

            $action = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('action');

            if ("addWholeSale" == $action) {
              $FormKey = 
              $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey');
              $Formkeyget=$FormKey->getFormKey();

              try {
                $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('id');
                $productOptions = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('options');
                //$productRepository = 
                $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
                // $product = $productRepository->getById($productId);
                $product = $this->_initProduct($productId);
                if ($product) {
                $productName = $product->getName();
                $productQty = $productOptions["qty"];
                $optionId = 
                str_replace('superattr[','',$productOptions["option_id"]);
                $optionId = str_replace('][qty]','',$optionId);
                $optionId = explode("][",$optionId);
                $optionId = $optionId[1];
                $option_value_id = $productOptions['option_value_id'];
                $options = array($optionId => $option_value_id );

                if ($productQty > 0) {
                  $params = array(
                  'form_key' => $Formkeyget,
                  'product' => $product->getId(),
                  'wholesaler'=>true,
                  'super_attribute' => $options,
                  'qty'   => $productQty //quantity of 
                  product
                  );
                  $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                  $this->cart->save();
                }

              }
              $arrResponse['success'] = "true";
              $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("$productName is successfully added 
              to bag") );
              echo json_encode($arrResponse);

              } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
              $arrResponse['success'] = "false";
              // $this->_loggerInterface->critical($e);
              $this->messageManager->addError(__("Error! some products 
              could not added to bag.") );
              //return parent::_goBack();
              } catch (Exception $ex) {
              $arrResponse['success'] = "false";
              // $this->_loggerInterface->critical($e);
              $this->messageManager->addError(__("Error! some products 
              could not added to bag.") );
              //return parent::_goBack();
              }
            }
```